# Bullets change direction with character

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

So I'm making a simple game with a character that can shoot, and the shooting works except that when the character turns the bullet reverses direction. I understand why this is happening so my question would be, is there a way I can remove the bullet from the array while keeping its current velocity so it ignores the direction of the character?

```
-(void)spinTapped
{

        CCSprite *bullet = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"rwby_bullet.png"];
        bullet.position = ccp(self.character.position.x , self.character.position.y+25);
        [bullets addObject:bullet];
        [self addChild:bullet z:-1];


}
```

then in the update:

```
if(isRight) bulletVelocity = 10;
    else if(isLeft) bulletVelocity = -10;

    for(CCSprite *bullet in bullets)
    {
        bullet.position = ccp(bullet.position.x + bulletVelocity + scrollVelocity, bullet.position.y);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create each bullet, set a tag.  Make it 10 for right facing and -10 for left facing, and then just add the tag for the velocity value.
-(void)spinTapped
{

```
    CCSprite *bullet = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"rwby_bullet.png"];
    bullet.position = ccp(self.character.position.x , self.character.position.y+25);
    if (isRight) {
       bullet.tag = 10;
    }
    else {
       bullet.tag = -10;
    }
    [bullets addObject:bullet];
    [self addChild:bullet z:-1];
```

}

```
NSMutableArray *deleteArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(CCSprite *bullet in bullets)
{
    bullet.position = ccp(bullet.position.x + bullet.tag + scrollVelocity, bullet.position.y);
    if (*bullet is off screen*) {
        [deleteArray addObject:bullet];
    }
}

for (CCSprite *bullet in deleteArray)
{
    [bullets removeObject:bullet];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works beautifully! Any tips on how to remove the objects from the array? In other words proper garbage collect? Right now I'm using [bullets removeObject: bullet]; is that the right way? Because at the moment this way causes the app to crash when it removes one while another is on the screen.

Comment: You could be having threading problems, or, if you are really messing up, you are removing objects from the array while iterating it.
I would recommend that you create a second array of bullets that need to be deleted.  Then delete those in a safe spot.